# If statements to change view

Tags: php, jquery, view, crud

I've got a JQuery function running on my create page for my contacts list. User selects one of three radio buttons - individual, team and company. And will fill out different forms depending on which one they chose.

Individual sees all the fields below. 
Team sees all but title. 
Company sees but company and title.

When users edit between individual/company, the view.php will still --> if individual changes to company (thus not needing company/title) the company/title will still show because they a) haven't backspaced the values and b) technically isn't deleted. I'm fine with the criteria still sitting in the backend, but I want to add if statements to make sure that the individual is seeing the individual criteria, company seeing company criteria etc.

```
<body> 
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>

            <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Type</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Details</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Phone</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Email</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Address</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Extras</strong></th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        ?>
        <tr> 
            <td class= "r-Name"><?php echo $r['Name']; ?></td> 
            <td class= "r-Type"><?php echo $r['Contact_type']; ?></td> 
            <td class="r-Details"><?php echo $r['Title']. ', '.$r['Company']; ?></td>
            <td class="r-Phone"><?php echo $r['Phone']; ?></td> 
            <td class="r-Email"><?php echo $r['Email']; ?></td> 
            <td class="r-Address"><?php echo $r['Address']; ?></td> 
            <td class="r-Update"><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $r['id'] ?>">Edit</a></td>
            <td class="r-Delete"><a href='delete.php?id=<?php echo $r['id']?>'>Delete</a></td>


             </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </table>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: and what is the actual question? wher is the code related to that?

Comment: Well I'm not too sure. As you can see, the current code just shows everything irrespective of what type of contact is added. How do I go about adding the if statements to make it more individua/company/team specific?

Comment: So you mean for example if `team` is ticked on your `radio button` only the rows will show are the one's belong to `team` ?

Comment: My example is that if individual is selected. Then the user decides to edit the individual into a company contact. The individual contacts 'company' and 'title' are still there because the JQuery function is just hiding the forms, not deleting them.

Comment: where the dropdown and the jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your jquery code

```
 $("yourinput_id").prop('disabled', true); //to disable
 $("yourinput_id").prop('disabled', false);//to enable 
 /*so that the form will ignore the input when passed to php, regardless of 
 visibility*/
```